# Can the main activity be able to grab elements from two XML files?

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-fragments

UPDATE WITH CODE (Sorry for crappy formatting of my code, some reason it had problems allowing me to post it so I had to mess with the lines for a whole to get it to allow me to save thisedit)

Here is the idea. I have an app that works with Clarifia's image recognition. I generated the app using Google's pre built navegation bar, so there is extra xml files and code for that, but it can be ignored the two needed for this is activity_main.xml and content_main.xml. anyways in content_main.xml it is a linear layout that has an imageview and a listview. My goal is to dynamically generate the listview with a list of BUTTONS. each button will have setText() done to it to give it a tag, so for example if a image selected is a dog, and the tags are dog, animal, etc, then that many buttons will be generated, with a setText() of one button being dog, the other button being animal, etc . now Since I have to do a network call, the network call is done in asynctask. After it is done, the method onPostExecute() is called and from there I get the tags. NOW since i got the tags, I want to call set an adapter that will hold an array of buttons, and loop geting the ID for each button and doing settext() on each button with the tags. from there i want to set the adapter to the list view..

Problems:

way to many to count, but I THINK i narrowed it down to me not knowing how to get the "views" from the second xml file to have the elements be used on the first xml file, because everything comes out NULL. I tried googling it but i just keep running into road blocks. I just want to name each button with a tag and put them into listview, but like i said, since these elements are in a different xml file than main_activity, I think this is  the problem. so here is the code per request.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
{
private static final String CLASS = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private Button selectButton;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private NavigationView navigationView;
private Clari

faiData cdata = null;
private ImageView imageview;
private ListView listview;
private TagAdapter adapter;
private List<Button> data;
protected Context context;
private GoogleApiClient client;
protected LinearLayout main;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
// THIS IS MY ATTEMPT TO DO THIS
// http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/UI/UsingtwolayoutxmlfileforoneActivity.htm
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
context = MainActivity.this;
main = new LinearLayout (this);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

// AUTO GENERATED stuff left out for nav bar, just showing this line*********

selectButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.select_button);
selectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final Intent media_intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        // START API OVER NET
        startActivityForResult(media_intent, cdata.getOKCode());
    }
});


// MY STUFF********************************************************
cdata = new ClarifaiData(this);
imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
{
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

if (requestCode == cdata.getOKCode() && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
{
    Uri image = intent.getData();

    if (image != null) {

        // LEFT OUT STUFF FOR IMAGE RESIZING***************************


        //************************************************** START LOOKING HERE***************************************
        new AsyncTask<Uri, Void, RecognitionResult>()
        {
            @Override
            protected RecognitionResult doInBackground(Uri... image)
            {
                // SO API CALL OVER INTERNET, SO NEEDED ASYNC
                return cdata.recognizeBitmap(image[0]);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(RecognitionResult result)
            {
                super.onPostExecute(result);

                if (cdata.getTags(result))
                {
                    selectButton.setEnabled(true);
                    selectButton.setText("Select a photo");







                    // MY ATTEMPT TO GET THE
                    //    http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/UI/UsingtwolayoutxmlfileforoneActivity.htm

                    LayoutInflater inflate = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    LinearLayout taglayout = (LinearLayout) inflate.inflate(R.layout.tag_list_item_trio_item, null);
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams parm = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    listview = (ListView) main.findViewById(R.id.tagview);
                    main.addView(taglayout, parm);
                    // this is a arraylist of tags that hold strings
                    List tags = cdata.getMapTags();
                    // data is a array of buttons, each button will be labled by each value in tags
                    data = new ArrayList<Button>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < tags.size(); i++)
                    {
                        // GET ID FOR EACH BUTTON AND PUT IT INTO ARRAY THEN SETTEXT
                        String loc = "button_item_" + i;
                        int ID = getResources().getIdentifier(loc, "id", getPackageName());
                        Button temp = (Button) main.findViewById(R.id.button_item_0);
                        temp.setText("TEST " + i);
                    }

                    // HERE IS THE PROBLEM, I NEED A WAY TO GET THE LAYOUT STUFF FROM MAIN  ACTIVITY
                    adapter = new TagAdapter(MainActivity.this, getResources().getIdentifier("tag_list_item_trio_item", "id", getPackageName()), data);
                    listview.setAdapter(adapter);




                }
                else
                    bottomToast(cdata.getRecError());
            }
        }.execute(image);
    } else {
        bottomToast(cdata.getLoadError());
    }
}
}
```

tagAdapter.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class TagAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Button> {
private Context context;
private List<Button> taglist;

public TagAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Button> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    Log.i("Test", "constructor " );
    this.context = context;
    this.taglist = objects;
}

@Override
public int getCount()
{

    return taglist.size();
}


getView(int, android.view.View, android.view.ViewGroup)
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.tag_list_item_dual_item, parent, false);

    final Button tag = taglist.get(position);

    View view = null;

    view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.tag_list_item_trio_item, parent, false);


    else
    {
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.tag_list_item_dual_item, parent, false);

        Button nameTextView = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.first_button_dual_item);
        nameTextView.setText("test");

        Button nameTextView2 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.second_button_dual_item);
        nameTextView2.setText("test2");

    }


    return view;

}
}
```

content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:gravity="center|bottom"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">



<ImageView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:id="@+id/image_view"
android:background="#653fff"
android:layout_weight="0.5"
android:padding="1dp" />

<ListView
android:id="@+id/tagview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="0.35"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:padding="5dp"
android:background="#68343f"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:textAlignment="center" />


<ImageView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/imageView"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:textAlignment="center"
    />

<Button
android:id="@+id/select_button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/sel_image"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
android:paddingLeft="24dp"
android:paddingRight="24dp"
android:background="#3d88ec" />



</LinearLayout>
```

tag_list_item_trio.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:textAlignment="center"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:orientation="horizontal">



<Button
android:id="@+id/button_item_0"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
android:background="#000000"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:text="TEST 1"
android:textColor="#ffffff"
    />

<Button
android:id="@+id/button_item_1"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
android:background="#000000"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:text="TEST 2"
android:textColor="#ffffff"
    />

<Button
android:id="@+id/button_item_2"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="5dp"

android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
android:background="#000000"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:text="TEST 3"
android:textColor="#ffffff"
    />


</LinearLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:textAlignment="center"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:orientation="horizontal">



<Button
android:id="@+id/button_item_0"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
android:background="#000000"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:text="TEST 1"
android:textColor="#ffffff"
    />

<Button
android:id="@+id/button_item_1"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
android:background="#000000"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:text="TEST 2"
android:textColor="#ffffff"
    />

<Button
android:id="@+id/button_item_2"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="5dp"

android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
android:background="#000000"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:text="TEST 3"
android:textColor="#ffffff"
    />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you should know is a Listview and its items are virtualized or recycled/reused or duplicated if i should say. so from how i see it i think your approach is off.

This is how i suggest you rectify it, before i get to that i want to clarify the way i understood a portion of your requirement

> My goal is to dynamically generate the listview with a list of BUTTONS. each button will have setText() done to it to give it a tag, so for example if a image selected is a dog, and the tags are dog, animal, etc, then that many buttons will be generated, with a setText() of one button being dog

so you are saying you want a listView with 4 buttons on each row.

Do this, _i am taking relevant portions.

```
private ListView listview; //your listview
private TagAdapter adapter; // your adapter
//we are in oncreate
//i have no knowledge on cdata so bare with me here
//now remove List<Button> data; from your code
```

we have jumped to the TagAdapter class

```
private Context context;
//private List<Button> taglist; remove this also
private ArrayList<TheClassThatContainsTags> myTags;//i am assuming this will be cdata or? 
//but this list should contain what setText() for a button will get its text

public TagAdapter(Context context) { //this is how your constructor will look
super(context);
Log.i("Test", "constructor " );
this.context = context;
//here you start your async task and put your async task logic here
//if the async task requires some objects or items which is not in this class
// since this is a separate class, you can inject them, when i say inject
// put them in the constructor of TagAdapter like you inject the Context 
//object instance, so it might change to 
// public TagAdapter(Context context,OneMoreClassIfIWant omciiw) {
// here you aysnc task will execute, now when onPostExecute is triggered/
//called you will do the following, but so remove all the code lines
// you currently have under onPostExecute
// onPostExecute has triggered
myTags = // the tag items result from onpostExecute 
//now your myTags Arraylist of type TheClassThatContainsTags has been
//instantiated
}
```

we are now moving to getCount still in your custom adapter

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
return (myTags == null) ? 0 : myTags.size();
}
```

we are now moving to getView still in your custom adapter

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
//in your posted getview, did you edit that too? if not does it give you errors?
//nevermind
// what you do here is check if convertView is null and instantiate it
// the position here in your method parameter is the index in your myTags
// list
if(convertView == null){
  //guess you know how to do this. it should be the same as your old
//getview minus this  final Button tag = taglist.get(position); 
// and the line below it.
}
//here we are still in the getview - what you do is ,
 you find what particular button you want by convertView.findViewById()
//my understanding as i pointer out is you want to have 4 buttons in a row
//it should be something like this
Button b = convertView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
b.setText(getItem(position));//getItem() is an instance method for the 
//class you are extending, and it returns an Object of Type T, which in my
//example is TheClassThatContainsTags.class;
// and you can do the same for the next 3 buttons
 }
```

we are out of your getview and custom adapter class , and we are in your oncreate .
here set when you need your tags then you do
     tagAdapter = new TagAdapter(context,anyIfDesired_OtherInjections);
    listview.setAdatper(tagAdapter);

now you are done. Hope it helps, also please read listview and Arraylist Adapter so you get a foresight of what you are doing and what i have posted here. it will help you trim down the hours you waste, if you spend 12 hours on the docs your will spend 5 minutes writing this and the next time you want to replicate it will be the same 5 minutes.

Be good sir and wish you success.

Comment: I am still pretty new to adapters, I know my example I am going off, the adapter class I made overrides the method getView() and within it, it uses LayoutInflater, but are you saying to us LayoutInflater in the main activity, or to call the getView method in main activity from the adapter object? or both?

thank you for the reply btw :)

Comment: please check my edit Sir @TannerSummers  and when i talked about layoutInflaters i was trying to give you a little information on who process xml layout to view objects, that is why you have it in your getview because you are converting the second xml file to a java object mainly the View class, so no play in your getview

Comment: Yes, it makes more sense, I think I understand it, but I have to play around with it, would you mind looking at snippets of my code? I think it may help. I been stuck on this for over 12 hours so I am very mad with it =/

Comment: yes, i would not mind, paste them and ask/tell me what you want to do and i will look at it before i end my day today, safe to say i might help you fix your problem - no more long hours, :) @TannerSummers , so feel free sir

Comment: thank you , I will try to do it soon, I got a lot of junk code to go through, first :)

Comment: Thank you so much, i'll implement it soon. I know I should have read the docs, but the problem was I was not sure which ones to read. This project is for school and we are short timed, so I just trying to learn but also get it done faster, but i really appreciate the help!